# Ant Design react - change default spinner for all components

Tags: reactjs, spinner, antd

I need to change the default spinner for all components at once. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to change the style of Spinner?

Comment: I want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spinners or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner instead of default look

Comment: Then instead of importing antd spinner, you can import spinner from these?

Comment: I am not talking about importable spinner, I mean default spinner for antd components like table or list in loading state

Comment: Okay, I got it working, let me write the answer for you

Comment: Thanks, it would be great...

Answer (score 3):

The Table component of Antd is having `loading` props. Generally, a boolean value is used for loading status to display or hide the Spinner, which is correct. **But one can also add object instead of boolean.**

[image]

On clicking object, it'll redirect you to [Spin Antd component API](https://ant.design/components/spin/#API).

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple properties of `<Spinner />` component and we can use these in `<Table loading={{size: 'large'}} />`. But the one which we need is indicator property because it accepts **ReactNode**. So, now the things which are left is to add the `<Loader />` from [react-loader-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner).

```
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";

const Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const loaderIcon = (
        <Loader type="Puff" color="#00BFFF" height={200} width={200} />
    );
    
    return (
      <Table
        {...this.state}
        loading={{ indicator: loaderIcon }}
        pagination={{ position: [this.state.top, this.state.bottom] }}
        columns={tableColumns}
        dataSource={state.hasData ? data : null}
        scroll={scroll}
      />  
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry for this huge code, I forked Antd example and then edited things inside that.

[Antd Table Dynamic settings code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-table-spinner-ggixi)

Comment: Yeah, I am aware about this functionality too. But what if I have 20 different tables across the website? Plus I don't want to do a research for ALL my antd components that support 'loading' state and add this hint there. The initial question was about changing this loading indicator everywhere in the website without adding it to all antd components manually

Comment: Then how about creating a reusable component with this functionality and replacing all your Table components with the reusable one? I think this is the only way of doing it

Comment: That's the only option left. If you find something better then you can tell us.